# Split and Merge Image wthout loss in image quality in Java

Tags: java, image, merge

I want split an image in number of chunks and merge again to create original image
I used this method to spit image http://kalanir.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html and for merge used this http://kalanir.blogspot.in/2010/02/how-to-merge-multiple-images-into-one.html
But after merging i fount that my new image size is reduce compare to original.
How i do split and merging of image without loosing any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you are:

- reading files into memory RGB data
- splitting
- joining them
- writing a new file

But in that case:

- When reading the JPEGs you are obtaining unencoded, uncompressed, lossless data.
- When you join them you are encoding again (lossing data) to generate the file.

If the second encoding doesn't do what the original software that encoded the image did, it'll be different.

A starting point is using **the same JPEG quality**. You can indicate a number from 1 to 100 indicating how much quality you want to keep at a size cost. That number should be at least equal to the number used to encode the original image.

I don't know how exactly to get that or to write that using the libraries you've used, but it should be available.

Comment: Like you pointed out partially is that every time you save a jpg compressed image data gets lost. So when the data is read back and saved again the quality degrades again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different image processing java api's like [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/), [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/),  [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)...etc